# Lion iCal like NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am trying to create an NSWindow like the one in Lion iCal (http://www.lutrindigital.cc/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/lion_ical_preview-400x275.png) I mean with a custom titlebar.

This application will be in the Mac App Store, so private API are prohibited.

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this: http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame

Comment: I suppose. You don't call any private API-s, just replacing one method in unusual way.